# Retail Database Design - Multiple Products with different accessories

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to design a MySQL database for an existing content-on-page retail website.  We have multiple products by different manufacturers, and we have different accessory options for each product, although some share the same accessories.  I'm stuck on designing the accessories TABLE(s)

Product 1 has 23 accessories - 9 color options, 4 door options, 4 leg options, 4 trivet options, 1 variable speed blower option, 1 fire screen option.

Product 2 has - 4 door options, 4 leg options, 1 variable speed blower option, 1 fire screen option (shares these options with Product 1).  Product 2 also has a leg adapter option, a pedestal option, and two ash drawer options.

Product 3 has 27 accessories - 9 color options, 8 door options, 4 leg options, 4 trivet options, 1 variable speed blower option, and 1 fire screen option.  The color options share the same post-fix, but have a different prefix (prod1.BLUE / prod3.BLUE).  The leg options are the same for all products.  The blower and fire screen are different from Product 1.

Do I need a separate accessories TABLE for each model?  Thanks in advance for the assistance, and if I have committed any faux pas, my bad.  This is my first question, please go easy! :)

Comment: I'm going to regret saying this but in the accessories field you could use csv separated values linking to each product that uses it and the explode on , then use a for each statement

Comment: I don't think my answer is by far the best option but I certainly do think you shouldn't use another table for the sake of just having another table

Comment: @LiamSorsby : you destroy any chance at enforcing referential integrity, so as accessories change without a lot of logic you'd have stale ids in the accessory list with your design.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer: For most applications, you're correct.  In retail, an entity / value table makes more sense than dozens of accessories tables.

Comment: I'm not advocating dozens of accessory tables.  I'm advocating a single product <-> accessory join table.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer is on the right track.   Accessories are products, and can be stored safely in the product table.   But the *associations* between products and their accessories should be stored in a many-to-many join table, so that they can be identified, searched for, categorized, etc.    This is a well-established database design pattern in retail, and can be done in a high-performance, conformant, and normalized design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

My original answer missed the point about the needing to "share" accessories, what with the question being about having a SEPARATE table for each model. It was my misunderstanding.

If you need to "share" accessories with two or more models, that implies a many-to-many relationship. That is,

- a model can have zero one or more accessories.
- an accessory can be related to zero one or more models.

To resolve a many-to-many relationship like this, we add another table, and remove the `model_id` column from the `accessories` table.

A row in the table will represent the relationship between an `accessory` and a `model`. This table will have a **foreign key** (`model_id`) to the `models` table and a **foreign key** (`accessory_id`) to the `accessories` table.

So, the `accessories` table would be a list of all available options:

```
accessories
id  description
--  --------------------
 1  color option black
 2  color option blazing red
 3  color option burnt umber
 4  color option chocolate
 5  color option deep red
 6  door option 1
 7  door option 2
 8  good blower
 9  quieter blower
10  fancy legs
11  fancy dancy legs
```

If model 101 has accessories: color options of black and burnt umber, and fancy legs, the rows in the model_accessories table would look like this:

```
model_accessories
model_id accessory_id
-------- ------------
     101            1
     101            3
     101           10
```

model_id 101 is a reference to the id column the models table, and the accessory_id is a reference to the id column in the accessories table.

Model 102 could share some of those same accessories, as well have different ones:

```
     102            1
     102            2
     102            3
     102            4
     102           11
```

Usually, there is a UNIQUE constraint placed on the combination of `(model_id, accessory_id)`, so the same accessory isn't associated two (or more) times.

Sometimes, there are attributes on the relationship. For example, the list price of an accessory may be different on different models. To support this, an attribute column (`list_price` could be added on the `model_accessories` relationship table.

The target of the foreign keys don't necessarily need to be separate tables; these could both reference the same `products` table. (That's why I chose to use `model` and `accessories` as table names in my examples.)

If we consider both `models` and `accessories` to both be `products`, then these can be stored in the same `products` table.

So, a `products` table could be:

```
products
id   description
---  --------------------
101  trail blazer
102  cabin inferno
103  cottage conflagration
  1  color option black
  2  color option blazing red
  3  color option burnt umber
  4  color option chocolate
  5  color option deep red
  6  door option 1
  7  door option 2
  8  good blower
  9  quieter blower
 10  fancy legs
 11  fancy dancy legs
```

The `model_accessories` table would remain the same, but both columns in that table would be foreign keys to the `products.id` column.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (downvoted, no reason given, but likely because it missed the point about "sharing" accessories. The approach in the answer below assumes that each accessory is associated with exactly ONE model. I thought the OP was meaning to create a model_101_accessories table, a model_102_accessories table, with nothing shared.

---

<strike>No, you don't need a separate table, if you store the accessories as rows in the table, rather than as columns.</strike>

Include the `model_id` in the `accessories` table, so you know which accessories go with which model.

```
model_accessories
id  model_id   description
--  --------   --------------------
 1       101   color option black
 2       101   door option 1
 3       101   good blower
 4       101   quieter blower

 5       102   color option 1
 6       102   color option 2
 7       102   color option 3
 8       102   color option 4
 9       102   door option 1
10       102   door option 2
11       102   fancy legs
12       102   fancy dancy legs
```

All the options are together in one table. But the rows `where model_id=101` are associated with the product model `id=101`. The rows `where model_id=102` are associated with the product model row with `id=102`.

A foreign key constraint can enforce that the only values that are allowed in the `accessories.model_id` column are values that are found in the `model.id` column.

Comment: You miss the point.  The models can share acessories, so that if the description to `door option 1` ever changes to `super duper door option 1` it doesn't have to be updated multiple times.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer: I did miss the point about the accessories needing to be shared. I missed that. I thought the OP was talking about creating a separate accessories table for each model. (That's likely the reason for the downvote on the answer.) I've updated the answer, but left the original answer that was downvoted. To resolve a many-to-many tables relationship, we add a third table, with foreign keys to the each of the two parent tables. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation spencer! The people behind StackOverflow are so helpful, I love it! :)

Comment: A single accessory can be associated with many many products, and vice versa.   A model-->accessory join table is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a separate table for each product -- that's madness.  You describe a many-many join, which is usually implemented using a table that can join accessories to product/model.  Assuming you have IDs for each product and accessory:

```
| product | accessory |
| 5       | 4         |
| 5       | 5         |
| 5       | 6         |
| 5       | 7         |
| 6       | 4         |
| 6       | 5         |
| 6       | 6         |
| 6       | 7         |
| 6       | 8         |
| 6       | 9         |
```

In this table, product 5 (say, an iPad 2) can have accessory 4, 5, 6, and 7 (covers).  Because the way these covers are designed, they also work with product 6 (an iPad 3).  Accessories 8 and 9 are designed specifically for product 6, and won't work with product 5.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Paul - This was exactly what I was trying to do and for some reason couldn't get my mind around,even though it is exactly how I did my manufacturer TABLE. Thank you!

Comment: @wibblywobblyjoe: you may want to define each of those columns as a foreign key to its parent table. (The selected answer omits any mention of the foreign key constraints which are normally implemented.)

Comment: +1 @PaulProgrammer: this is a good answer. (Resolving a many-to-many relationship with an intermediate table is the normative pattern.)

Comment: I would add a "category" column, which would include the *nature* of the relationship between product and accessory (from a controlled vocabulary):  e.g. "ReplacementPart", "Enhancement", "Carrier", etc. as appropriate to the industry, and the type of product.

Comment: @Curt I agree, there's many things you could add as join metadata, but the OP doesn't specify any further needs.  You can add start/stop dates to determine when to offer or stop offering accessories, you can add prices to change prices when things are bought together... etc.